# CSV - Merging 2 files having headers in random sequence

Tags: python, csv

I am looking for help to merge 2 csvs, having random order of headers and data. Sample data is as below.

**csv-1**:

```
apple,orange,banana,pineapple
10,20,30,40
11,21,31,41
```

**csv-2**:

```
orange,apple,pineapple
22,21,23
32,31,33
```

**final_csv**:

```
apple,orange,banana,pineapple
10,20,30,40
11,21,31,41
21,22,,23
31,32,,33
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

read into csv and concat with pandas:

```
import pandas as pd
df1 = pd.read_csv('file1.csv')
df2 = pd.read_csv('file1.csv')

df = pd.concat([df1, df2])
df.to_csv('output.csv', index=False)
```

Comment: does it concat based on headers? and what if in CSV-2 columns are missing or not matching?

Comment: I think you should add `index = False` to the `df.to_csv('output.csv')` function call since you don't want indices from both dataframe to linger in the output

Comment: @Nick yeah, it concat based on headers

Comment: @user696969 added